# Weird variable binding in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in Haskell that's part of a Brainfuck intepreter (my favorite first medium-sized project when I learn a new language) :

```
type Program = String
type Pointer = Int
type Stack = [Int]

data ExecutionState = ExecutionState {
  programPointer :: Pointer,
  program :: Program,
  stackPointer :: Pointer,
  stack :: Stack
} deriving (Eq, Show)

moveBackwards :: ExecutionState -> ExecutionState
moveBackwards (ExecutionState pp p sp s) = ExecutionState (pp-1) p sp s

curr :: ExecutionState -> Char
curr execState = (stack execState) !! (stackPointer execState)

currByte :: ExecutionState -> Int
currByte execState = (program execState) !! (programPointer execState)


comeBackToOpeningBracket :: ExecutionState -> IO ExecutionState
comeBackToOpeningBracket executionState = result
  where 
    result = if currByte executionState /= 0 
      then comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth 0 (moveBackwards executionState)
      else return executionState

    comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth n executionState 
      | n == 0 = do 
        print $ map programPointer [executionState, moveBackwards executionState, prev] -- debug
        case curr executionState of
          '[' -> return executionState
          ']' -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth 1 prev
          _ -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth 0 prev
      | otherwise = case curr executionState of
        '[' -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth (n-1) prev
        ']' -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth (n+1) prev
        _ -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth n prev

    prev = moveBackwards executionState
```

If you don't know what brainfuck is, a quick recap (sorry for probably not using the correct technical terms): it consists of a `program` (some chars in a row, every char is a separate instruction), what I call here the `programPointer` (which says what char, or instruction, we're currently applying), a `stack` (actually it's an infinite array of bytes, here I took Integers instead) and a `stackPointer` which says which byte we're currently working on.

Each instruction has a specific effect (asking for input, changing values of the stack, etc), and here is the implementation of the ']' program char. It says that when you encounter it, and if the pointed byte on the stack is not 0, you go backwards till you meet the matching '['.

The return type of IO ExecutionState is needed to match that of other instructions (I know here I could return a plain ExecutionState without the print line, which is for debugging).

---

The rest of my program is the implementation for the others instructions, which all seem to work as expected.

When testing it on a Brainfuck program though, the output of the print was [37, 36, 37] ; the first value is OK (it's the location of the char directly before the ']', since we first move backwards once), the second is what I expect when moving backwards, but why 37 for the third ? Since my `moveBackward` function is pure (aaah, functionnal programming), it should print 36 twice, no ?
I assume this is because of some unknown (at least to me) variable binding rule (the fact of having prev = ... and then using prev again instead of inlining the expression), but I really don't get it, and I don't wanna write `(moveBackwards executionState)` everywhere instead of first binding it to prev and the using prev, which is nicer and shorter.
Could you explain this behavior ?

Thanks !

PS : Is there an efficient way of properly debuging a Haskell program, since you can't write some 'print' lines everywhere like in most other languages ?

Comment: There's also still a type error in the `curr` and `currByte` functions. The `Int` and `Char` should be swapped.

Answer (score 5):

You use the same name: `executionState`, for two different variables. Here's a version of your function with unique names:

```
comeBackToOpeningBracket :: ExecutionState -> IO ExecutionState
comeBackToOpeningBracket executionState1 = result
  where 
    result = if currByte executionState1 /= 0 
      then comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth 0 (moveBackwards executionState1)
      else return executionState1

    comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth n executionState2
      | n == 0 = do 
        print $ map programPointer [executionState2, moveBackwards executionState2, prev] -- debug
        case curr executionState2 of
          '[' -> return executionState2
          ']' -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth 1 prev
          _ -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth 0 prev
      | otherwise = case curr executionState2 of
        '[' -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth (n-1) prev
        ']' -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth (n+1) prev
        _ -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth n prev

    prev = moveBackward executionState1
```

If you enable the `-Wall` option by running `ghc -Wall MyFile.hs` or putting `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}` at the top of the file you will be warned automatically about this problem (called "shadowing"):

```
T.hs:31:41: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for ‘executionState’ shadows the existing binding
      bound at T.hs:25:26
   |
31 |     comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth n executionState 
   |
```

P.S. you can debug more easily using functions from [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html):

```
import Debug.Trace (traceShow)

...

    comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth n executionState2
      | n == 0 && traceShow (map programPointer [executionState2, moveBackwards executionState2, prev]) True =
        case curr executionState2 of
          '[' -> return executionState2
          ']' -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth 1 prev
          _ -> comeBackToOpeningBracketWithDepth 0 prev
...
```

That way you can remove `IO`.

Comment: Probably worth a mention of enabling warnings to report shadowing.

Comment: Ok great, thanks ! Didn't know about that Debug library but seems nice !